# When I use input() my code doesn't appear when I run it

Tags: python

I have now changed my code but there it says invalid syntax for the last line, how do I fix this? I changed the last line to global status before displayMenu but it seems to be causing a problem to my code

```
users = {}
status = ""

def displayMenu():
    status = raw_input("Are you a registered user? y/n? Press q to quit: ")  
    if status == "y":
        oldUser()
    elif status == "n":
        newUser()

def newUser():
    createLogin =("Create login name: ")

    if createLogin in use
```

Comment: Are you using Python 3 or Python 2? If you're still using Python 2 you _should_ use `raw_input`, the Python 2 `input` function is dangerous. In Python 3, the old  `input` function no longer exists, and `raw_input` has been renamed to `input`.

Comment: It looks like you _are_ using Python 2, so you should seriously consider upgrading to Python 3. In the mean time, change `status = input()("Are you a registered user? y/n? Press q to quit: ")` back to `status = raw_input("Are you a registered user? y/n? Press q to quit: ")`. And you need to fix those other `input()` lines in the same way.

Comment: thank you i have now posted an edit because it seems to have another problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems with that code. Eg,

```
createLogin =("Create login name: ")
```

just assigns the string `"Create login name: "` to the name `createLogin`. But I suspect that you want `"Create login name: "` to be a user prompt, so you need:

```
createLogin = raw_input("Create login name: ")
```

The last line of your script doesn't make much sense. I suspect that it's an attempt to use the `global` directive, but it's best to avoid that unless you *really* need it. And generally you *don't* really need it. :)

Here's a repaired version of your code. Note that we aren't saving the `users` dictionary to disk, so when the program exits any information that was entered will be lost.

```
from __future__ import print_function

users = {}

def displayMenu():
    status = raw_input("Are you a registered user? y/n? Press q to quit: ")
    if status == "y":
        oldUser()
    elif status == "n":
        newUser()
    return status

def newUser():
    createLogin = raw_input("Create login name: ")
    if createLogin in users: # check if login name exists
        print ("\nLogin name already exist!\n")
    else:
        createPassw = raw_input("Create password: ")
        users[createLogin] = createPassw # add login and password
        print("\nUser created!\n")

def oldUser():
    login = raw_input("Enter login name: ")
    passw = raw_input("Enter password: ")

    # check if user exists and login matches password
    if login in users and users[login] == passw: 
        print("\nLogin successful!\n")
    else:
        print("\nUser doesn't exist or password error!\n") 

status = ""
while status != "q":
    status = displayMenu()
```

Comment: thank you very much! you're a life saver :) I really should use this website more